# TensorFlow 2.4.0 model.predict error when using array of Tensors as input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

According to [Keras Sequential Model .predict()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict) documentation, the model can use a variety of input forms, including:

> A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).

This is exactly what I am trying to do, namely use a "batch" of two Tensors as input to predict() and get two predictions as output in the following code:

```
test_batch = (img_tf1, img_tf2) # two Tensors in list
predictions = model.predict(test_batch)
```

However I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(32, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(32, 224, 3) dtype=float32>]
```

The shapes are as follows:

- Model input: `<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 224, 224, 3) dtype=float32`
- test_batch: `(<tf.Tensor: shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=float32>)`

Does anyone know where the problem lies? I believe I am using the API correctly, as specified by the documentation. My TensorFlow version is 2.4.0 installed with pip in a conda environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow treats them as separate inputs to the model as they are not stacked. You can do two things:

```
img1 = tf.expand_dims(img1, axis = 0) # in case you did not add batch dims.
img2 = tf.expand_dims(img2, axis = 0) # in case you did not add batch dims.

test_batch = (img1,img2)

test_batch = tf.experimental.numpy.vstack(test_batch)

preds = last_model.predict(test_batch)
```

Or you can create `tf.data.Dataset`, they will be batched later:

```
img1 = tf.random.uniform((32,32,3))
img2 = tf.random.uniform((32,32,3))

test_batch = [img1,img2] # store them in a list

test_batch = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_batch).batch(1)
```

We can see they have a batch dimension.

```
test_batch
<BatchDataset shapes: (None, 32, 32, 3), types: tf.float32>
```

After, they can be predicted:

```
preds = last_model.predict(test_batch)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. However what I don't understand is why the documentation says the model can take a list of Tensors as input. In that case wouldn't the first dimension be the batch size, i.e. the length of the list, and why can't TensorFlow interpret this correctly as the batch dimension?

Comment: *can take a list of Tensors as input*, in a case that model has multiple inputs. I think mosty likely, TensorFlow can not interpret the size of the list as the batch because it expects multiple inputs in that form. So one cleanest and best way to stack them into an array to create your batch.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution that I have found is to simply stack the two Tensors to create a batch dimension as follows:

```
test_batch = tf.stack([img_tf1, img_tf2])
predictions = model.predict(test_batch)
```